# Gitlab on OpenShift Origin gets stuck on "Symlinking existing certificates found in /etc/gitlab/trusted-certs"

Tags: gitlab, openshift-origin

I'm running the Openshift origin all in one, and the various project templates seem to work fine, except for gitlab.  When restarting the machine, or trying to restart the gitlab-ce pod, it seems to either take a really long time (just under 10m) or it fails due to timeout.  It always seems to get *stuck* at the same place.

How can i troubleshoot this deployment?

```
Thank you for using GitLab Docker Image!
Current version: gitlab-ce=8.14.1-ce.1

Configure GitLab for your system by editing /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb file
And restart this container to reload settings.
To do it use docker exec:

  docker exec -it gitlab vim /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
  docker restart gitlab

For a comprehensive list of configuration options please see the Omnibus GitLab readme
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md

If this container fails to start due to permission problems try to fix it by executing:

  docker exec -it gitlab update-permissions
  docker restart gitlab

Preparing services...
Starting services...
Configuring GitLab package...
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/runsvdir-start: line 24: ulimit: pending signals: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/runsvdir-start: line 34: ulimit: max user processes: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/runsvdir-start: line 37: /proc/sys/fs/file-max: Read-only file system
Configuring GitLab...


  * Moving existing certificates found in /opt/gitlab/embedded/ssl/certs

  * Symlinking existing certificates found in /etc/gitlab/trusted-certs
```

Comment: Having the same issue. Whenever Gitlab [re]starts the pod hangs there either timing out (although i've upped the time limit to 20 minutes) or eventually completing. Unsure of root cause as not limited by memory (have 3x 16GB nodes) and running manually won't help. Would really appreciate a little more insight here.

Answer (score 0):

Your process hangs on https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/~/dockerfile/

```
wrapper
```

line

you can run it manually by executing

```
docker run -it gitlab/gitlab-ce 'bash'
```

and entering there `wrapper`

If you manage to see

```
Starting Chef...
```

then everything after that should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this for me, turned out to be lack of memory. I was running AWS EC2 t1.micro - 1GB. To fix, I stopped the EC2 instance and upgraded to t2.small (2GB). I started the EC2 again, ran `free` to check the memory was available, and then ran the `docker run -ti gitlab/gitlab-ce` command again.

Also, this saved me a couple of times, to clear up a corrupted docker state:

`service docker stop
sudo rm -rf /var/run/docker
sudo rm /var/run/docker.*
service docker start`